# Can not start visual studio

Tags: 20.04, visual-studio-code

I can not start my visual studio. When I tried to run `code`, it said that

`/snap/code/35/electron-launch: line 28: /snap/code/35/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: No such file or directory /snap/code/35/usr/share/code/bin/code: line 45: /snap/code/35/usr/share/code/bin/../code: No such file or directory` 
I install it via Snap

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here download](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download)
a deb file from here and go to the directory where it's downloaded and type

`sudo apt install ./{nameofdebfile}`